# jquery center div at point

Tags: javascript, jquery, center

I am creating a div using jquery and I am trying to center it at a specific point. The text in the div is dynamic, and it's not centered in a particular parent html, but rather I want to center it on just a specific point.

So basically I have

```
var centerX = 100; // dynamically computer in my code
$('<div/>').text('sometext').css({'left': (centerPointX - $('#mydiv').width() / 2) + 'px'});
```

But the width of `mydiv` is not known until it is rendered, so I'm not sure how to go about centering at the x point. Do I need an outer container in which to center in relative to?

Comment: you will also have to determine the width of the `div` by code (or constant), then use a container and set the position relatively.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the width of the text?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `$('#mydiv')` only gets the element if it is available in the `DOM`.

So you would first be required to **inject the element** into the `DOM` and then access the width property . Otherwise it will be 0 when you try to access the width property of the element.

Comment: Ah yes, I was forgetting to append it before I tried to calculate the width.